# Delete Edges in Kpartite Graph

Tags: graphics

I need to make a K7,2 partite graph , with deleting 2 vertices and plus 2 more random edges , and after that my vertices should be green color.
I made the graph K7,2 and deleted 2 vertices with this code :
 `` Needs["Combinatorica`"]; a = CompleteGraph[7, 2]; b = 
 Fold[DeleteVertex, a, {3, 4}]; ShowGraph[b, 
 VertexLabel -> (Style[#, 18] & /@ Drop[Range[9], {3, 4}]), 
 ImageSize -> 200] `` 
But now i need something which can delete 2 more random edges , and plus color my vertices green

Thanks,

Comment: Angel, welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take [the introductory tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking [the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh). (3) Please remember to accept the answer that solves your problem, by clicking [the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t). 4) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
a = CompleteGraph[7, 2];
b = DeleteVertices[a, {3, 4}];
```

The functions you need to *delete randomly selected two edges* are the built-in function `RandomChoice` and the `Combinatorica` functions `Edges` and  `DeleteEdges`.

```
deletededges = RandomChoice[Edges[b], 2];
c = DeleteEdges[b, deletededges];

Row[{ShowGraph[a, VertexStyle -> Disk[.05], VertexColor -> Green, 
   VertexLabel -> True, BaseStyle -> Large, ImageSize -> 300,
   PlotLabel -> Style[#, 16] &@"CompleteGraph[7,2]"], 
  ShowGraph[b, VertexStyle -> Disk[.05], VertexColor -> Green, 
   VertexLabel -> True, BaseStyle -> Large, ImageSize -> 300,
   PlotLabel -> Row[Style[#, 16] & /@ {"Deleted vertices: " , {3, 4}}]],
  ShowGraph[c, VertexStyle -> Disk[.05], VertexColor -> Green, 
   VertexLabel -> True, BaseStyle -> Large, ImageSize -> 300,
   PlotLabel -> Row[Style[#, 16] & /@ {"Deleted edges: " , 
       ToString /@ deletededges}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot dude , you made my day +1

Comment: Angel, my pleasure; glad it worked for your needs. Welcome to mma.se.